# How to rename the shell current working directory

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am using gnome-terminal. I often work on large projects where there are lots of sub-directories and I have to compile them from the terminal. It's a very problematic to work with long-path terminal prompt while you have one monitor.

Assume you are in a directory,

```
sbmaruf@lenovo:/sys/dev/block/7:6/bdi/subsystem/7:7/power$
```

Now while I am using the terminal, is there any tricks or shortcuts to make the current address to a dummy string or text so that it may easy to work. Like if I want to show the above address as,

```
sbmaruf@lenovo:proj1$
```

where `proj1 = /sys/dev/block/7:6/bdi/subsystem/7:7/power`. I want do it on the go. like while I am using the terminal can I do it in a short amount of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this feature to your shell by modifying your `~/.bashrc` file.

Assuming a standard configuration, in your `~/.bashrc` file change the definition of `PS1`, which is the prompt, from:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

to the following:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]${PROMPT:-\w}\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:${PROMPT:-\w}\$ '
fi
```

You are replacing both the `\w`s with `${PROMPT:-\w}`.

In a prompt string, the `\w` means the current directory.  The `${VAR:-VALUE}` means use VALUE unless the variable VAR is set and not null.  Therefore it is possible to override showing the current directory while a shell variable is set.

Now you can set the alias with:

```
sbmaruf@lenovo:/sys/dev/block/7:6/bdi/subsystem/7:7/power$ PROMPT=proj1
sbmaruf@lenovo:proj1$
```

And unset it with:

```
sbmaruf@lenovo:proj1$ unset PROMPT
```

Or set it as null:

```
sbmaruf@lenovo:proj1$ PROMPT=
sbmaruf@lenovo:/sys/dev/block/7:6/bdi/subsystem/7:7/power$
```

Comment: For clarity, you might want to use a more descriptive variable name, like OVERRIDE_PROMPT_WD or something.

Comment: @Martin Thornton : I'm now using powerline shell now. https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell#customization
Is there any way to customize now.

Answer (score 2):

If your prompt uses `pwd` you can define a symbolic link e.g. in your home directory: `ln -s /sys/dev/block/7:6/bdi/subsystem/7:7/power ~/proj1`.

Then `cd ~/proj1` and your prompt should become (almost) what you want i.e. `sbmaruf@lenovo:~/proj1$`